# Bootstrap tooltips changes

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

is it possible to change tooltip on some element when button is clicked?
`DIV` with some tooltip `DIV`
`BUTTON`

after user click on button:
`DIV` with other tooltip `DIV`
`BUTTON`

Comment: Please add code of your progress till now.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this one, but its not with bootstrap tooltip

```
$(".switch").click(function() {
        $(".tooltip").toggle();
        if ($("#tp1").text() == "Active") {
            $("#tp1").text("Stop");
        }
        else {
            $("#tp1").text("Active");
        }
    });

<div class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></label>
</div> <div class="tooltip fade bottom in" style="display: block;top: 52px;width: 115px;left: 16.5px;"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div id="tp1" class="tooltip-inner">Active</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a best working code for you! Try this below code.

```js
$(function() {
  var $toolTip = $('#tooltip-example');
  var originalTitle = $toolTip.attr('title');
  $toolTip.tooltip({placement: "bottom"});

  $toolTip.click(function() {
    $toolTip.attr('title', 'New Hello World Message').tooltip('fixTitle').tooltip('show');
  });
  
  $(document).on("mouseout","#tooltip-example",function()
  {
    $toolTip.attr('title',originalTitle).tooltip('fixTitle').tooltip('show');
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="tooltip-example" data-tooltip title="Hello world">Click me</button>
```